# KnexJS Transaction

Tags: node.js, knex.js

How can I execute this transaction? My problem is the correct use of `for` instruction.

```
app.db.transaction(function (trx) {

    app.db('sales_record_products').transacting(trx).insert(products)
     .then(_ => {

      for (let i = 0; i < stockProducts.ids.length; i++) {
        app.db('products').transacting(trx).where('id',stockProducts.ids[i]).update({quantity: stockProducts.results[i]})
.then(_ => {

        })

      }

    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback)
  })
  .then(_ => res.status(200).json({success: true}))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using something like

```
// Start a database transaction
return app.db.transaction(function (trx) {

    // Insert products
    return trx.insert(products)
      .then(function (newIds) {

        // Product inserted, you have the new database id in newIds

        // Update all product individually but sequentially
        return Promise.mapSeries(stockProducts, function (sp) {

          // Update a single product
          return trx
            .table('products')
            .where('id', stockProducts.ids[i])
            .update({ quantity: stockProducts.results[i] });
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
I'm using knexjs

Comment: works.
Thanks for help

app.db.transaction(function (trx) {

    app.db('sales_record_products').transacting(trx).insert(products).then(_ => {
      return Promise.mapSeries(stockProducts.ids, function(a, index) {
        return app.db('products').transacting(trx).where('id', stockProducts.ids[index]).update({quantity: stockProducts.results[index]})
      }).then(trx.commit)
      .catch(trx.rollback)
    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback)
  })
  .then(_ => res.status(200).json({success: true}))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))